# How to Prepend a text to each read of a Stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, streamreader, prepend

I am querying a `REST Api` using `HTTP Client` that returns a stream of data.
So have a `System.IO.Stream` with me, this essentially looks like a `CSV` row like

```
ABC, 01-01-2018, SomeString
```

And I send this stream directly to SQLBulkInsert with Column Mapping and it all works fine.

But now I want to add another column to this `CSV` so that it looks like this

```
ID, ABC, 01-01-2018, SomeString
```

I am trying to find a way where I can prepend this data on the fly into the stream.

I can ofcourse create an collection from the incoming stream and add ID to the object and convert it back to a stream but that is not what I want to do ideally.

So, is there a way by which I can add some more data on each read without needing to create objects from stream and streaming the collection again.

Update -- I can also decorate a `StreamReader` to have a prepended `ReadLine`, but is that the best way to handle this ? Can I not do it on the stream ?

Comment: So you're wanting to add a new ID to every *line*? Are you guaranteed how the *consuming* side is reading it? It may not be doing per-line reads and so this points to needing to do something fairly invasive involving some buffering of your own.

Comment: Idea is to send this stream directly in DB, with added IDs, planning to use bulkInsert for that which accepts IDataReader,